# Custom membership provider and current endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf

I am writing custom membership provider for my WCF application and I need to know current endpoints URL in `ValidateUser()` method. 
How can I get this information about current channel that is used?

I have checked OperationContext, WebOperationContext and HttpContext. 
They are all null.

TIA

Mijalko

Comment: When you say WCF application... do you mean WCF Service?  If so how are you hosting?

Comment: Yes, WCF service. Currently, for test purpose, I am hosting it in Console application. But at the end it will be hosted in IIS